# Prototypes inheritance understanding

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var Class = function(){ // function constructor
this.className = 'Class';
}
Class.prototype.method = function(){ // open method
alert('method of ' + this.className);
}

var ClassSub = function(){ // function constructor of sub class
this.className = 'ClassSub';
}
ClassSub.prototype = new Class(); 

var objSub = new ClassSub(); 
objSub.method();
```

And I have one qustion:     `Class.prototype.method = function(){ // open method`

when we write like that we say that that prototype of our class will have this method.
So his  subclasses will have this method to.
But what i can't understand is 
why we can't just write

```
Class.method = function()
```

Comment: That syntax treats Class as an ordinary function object, not as a constructor of Class object instances.

Comment: @Jeffman - please speak clear. what are you pointing to (referring to)?

Comment: what is you question? are you saying what is the reason of using `classname.prototype.methodname` and why we are not using `classname.methodname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.method = function () {};`

That would just add a `method` property on the constructor function `Class`. Functions are objects and can hold data just like any other objects. However, the reason that will not add the `method` function to `Class` instances is simple: **that's not how prototypal inheritance is implemented in JavaScript**.

You should read about [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) and you will understand how the prototype chain is being setup and why adding members to a constructor function will not influence instances created using this constructor.

I think it's also worth mentionning that `ClassSub.prototype = new Class();` is not an efficient way of setting up the prototype chain since it will run the `Class` constructor's code.

In modern browsers you can simply use `Object.create` and there are shim for old browsers.

`ClassSub.prototype = Object.create(Class.prototype);`

Comment: I have read about it thank u... i guess i need some time to understand it...))

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `Class.method` creates a property for the *variable* `Class`. not the *instances* of `Class`.

```
var Class = function () { /* some code */ }
Class.method = function () { }
console.log(Class.method); // function () { }
console.log(new Class().method); // undefined

Class.prototype.method = function () { }
console.log(new Class().method); // function () { }
```